# Vue 3: Why vue yandex maps package doesn't work in vue 3 with defineCustomElement feature?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, yandex-maps

I have 2 projects with [vue yandex maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-yandex-maps) in vue 3:

**First project**

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-yandex-maps) first project where work vue yandex maps. In this project package registered like this:

**Code** `main.js` where registered vue-yandex-maps **components** from `js` file:

```
const { createApp } = require('vue');
import App from './App.vue';
import ymapPlugin from 'vue-yandex-maps/dist/vue-yandex-maps.esm.js';

const app = createApp(App);

app.config.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.startsWith('y'); // <= This is doesn't work
app.use(ymapPlugin);
app.mount('#app');
```

**Code** `MapComponent.vue`where used package vue-yandex-maps:

```html
<template>
  <yandex-map :coords="coords">
    <ymap-marker
      marker-id="123"
      :coords="coords"
      :marker-events="['click']"
    ></ymap-marker>
  </yandex-map>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MapComponent',
  setup() {
    return {
      coords: [54, 39],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**Code** `App.vue`where used component `MapComponent`:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <MapComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MapComponent from './components/MapComponent.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    MapComponent,
  },
};
</script>
```

**Second project**

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-ce-ymaps) second project where used new feature [defineCustomElement](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#definecustomelement) from vue version **3.2** and get error message when use package `vue-yandex-maps`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'offsetWidth')

**Code** `main.js` where registered `vue-yandex-maps` components from `js` file:

```
import { defineCustomElement } from './defineCustomElementWithStyles'
import App from './App.ce.vue'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'
import ymapPlugin from 'vue-yandex-maps/dist/vue-yandex-maps.esm.js'

customElements.define(
  'app-root',
  defineCustomElement(App, {
    plugins: [store, router, ymapPlugin],
  })
)
```

**Code** `defineCustomElementWithStyles.js`:

```
import { defineCustomElement as VueDefineCustomElement, h, createApp, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

const getNearestElementParent = (el) => {
  while (el?.nodeType !== 1 /* ELEMENT */) {
    el = el.parentElement
  }
  return el
}

export const defineCustomElement = (component, { plugins = [] }) =>
  VueDefineCustomElement({
    props: component.props,
    setup(props) {
      const app = createApp()

      // install plugins
      plugins.forEach(app.use)

      app.mixin({
        mounted() {
          const insertStyles = (styles) => {
            if (styles?.length) {
              this.__style = document.createElement('style')
              this.__style.innerText = styles.join().replace(/\n/g, '')
              getNearestElementParent(this.$el).prepend(this.__style)
            }
          }

          // load own styles
          insertStyles(this.$?.type.styles)

          // load styles of child components
          if (this.$options.components) {
            for (const comp of Object.values(this.$options.components)) {
              insertStyles(comp.styles)
            }
          }
        },
        unmounted() {
          this.__style?.remove()
        },
      })

      const inst = getCurrentInstance()
      Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context)
      Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides)
      console.log({ props })
      return () => h(component, props)
    },
  })
```

**Code** `Home.ce.vue` where used component `MapComponent`:

```html
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Home',
}
</script>

<script setup>
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.ce.vue'
import MapComponent from '@/components/MapComponent.ce.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <h2>Home</h2>
  <HelloWorld msg="hello world" />
  <MapComponent />
</template>
```

**Code** `MapComponent.ce.vue` where used package `vue-yandex-maps`:

```html
<template>
  <yandex-map :coords="coords">
    <ymap-marker marker-id="123" :coords="coords" :marker-events="['click']"></ymap-marker>
  </yandex-map>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MapComponent',
  setup() {
    return {
      coords: [54, 39],
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.ymap-container {
  height: 600px;
}
</style>
```

**Question**

Where I have **error** in [second project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-ce-ymaps) where I use `vue-yandex-maps` with `defineCustomElement`?

Comment: Likely because web components use shadow DOM and you can't use them for components that were designed to be used with global DOM. You can be pretty sure that wrappers for third-party widgets were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vue-yandex-maps` [renders a map container](https://github.com/PNKBizz/vue-yandex-map/blob/cef23ed/src/YMap.js#L283-L307) with a [randomly generated ID](https://github.com/PNKBizz/vue-yandex-map/blob/cef23ed/src/YMap.js#L62) that is [passed to the `ymaps.Map` constructor](https://github.com/PNKBizz/vue-yandex-map/blob/cef23ed/src/YMap.js#L179), which later uses it to query the `document` for the element. Unfortunately, the map container is rendered inside the Shadow DOM of the `app-root` custom element, which is hidden from `document` queries. The `document.querySelector()` thus returns `null`, and the `ymaps.Map` code tries to get the size of the container via the `null` reference, leading to the error you observed.

You would have to patch `vue-yandex-maps` yourself, or submit a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PNKBizz/vue-yandex-map/issues) to request a feature change, where you could pass in the map container element (from the custom element's Shadow DOM) instead of an ID. It looks like [`ymaps.Map` already accepts either an element or a string ID](https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#Map__param-parentElement), so no other change would be necessary.